# Jquery parseHTML not giving expected object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

Given I have this html string in javascript variable "data"

```
<div class="packery-item">        
        <img class="rsImg" src="/media/VERSIONS/images/blog/2013/04/heart-watercolor1_featured_image.jpg" alt="Article illustration"/>        
</div>
<div class="packery-item">        
        <img class="rsImg" src="/media/VERSIONS/images/blog/2013/04/planning_featured_image.jpg" alt="Article illustration"/>        
</div>
<div class="packery-item">
    <img src="/media/VERSIONS/images/galleries/2013/04/fashion_slideshow.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

When I run `$(data)`it returns something like:

```
[div.packery-item, text, div.packery-item, text, div.packery-item, text, div.packery-item, text, div.packery-item, text, div.packery-item, constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.8.3", size: function…]
```

I would expect it to return a list of div.packery-item only. What have I done wrong?

Comment: seems to show fine:: http://jsfiddle.net/Fw7vz/

Comment: can you post your script?

Comment: The newlines and spaces between the tags create text nodes containing whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the whitespace between the tags, they're being turned into text nodes so that there will be spacing between the elements.

```
var data = '<div class="packery-item">' +
        '<img class="rsImg" src="/media/VERSIONS/images/blog/2013/04/heart-watercolor1_featured_image.jpg" alt="Article illustration"/>' +
'</div>' +
'<div class="packery-item">' +
        '<img class="rsImg" src="/media/VERSIONS/images/blog/2013/04/planning_featured_image.jpg" alt="Article illustration"/>' +
'</div>' +
'<div class="packery-item">' +
    '<img src="/media/VERSIONS/images/galleries/2013/04/fashion_slideshow.jpg" alt="" />' +
'</div>'
```